# Get input value from element by name starts with... (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, input

i'm trying to get the value of an input that i get by the name attribute. This is my code:

```
$("input[name^='valor-unit-']").keyup(() => {
    console.log($(this).val())
})
```

But i get an error:

```
jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at w.fn.init.val (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.$.keyup (main.js:636)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
val @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
$.keyup @ main.js:636
dispatch @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
y.handle @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
```

Any idea?

Comment: There are more code that you have. Try to find the toLowerCase

Comment: @AlanGrosz It not because of `toLowerCase` it's because jQuery dont understand arrow functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
$("input[name^='valor-unit-']").keyup(function() {
    console.log($(this).val())
})
```

The problem is the `() =>` what I believe is a `typescript` way of creating a function.

The `() => {}` is called an `arrow function`

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds the this value (does not bind its own `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`). Arrow functions are always anonymous.

**Demo**

```js
$("input[name^='valor-unit-']").keyup(function() {
    console.log($(this).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="valor-unit-1" />
```

Comment: @KenRamirez No problem, happy to help